# What reverb plugins do you use?

Tags: reverb

In keeping with this months topic of reverb on Designing Sound, what are the reverb plugins you use most often? for Convolution/IR? Traditional? Weirder/non real?
(There is no right answer to this question of course, so I'll add my favourites below)

Convolution:
I own Altiverb
http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Altiverb

TL Space 
http://www.avid.com/US/products/TL-Space

and just bought Reverberate
http://www.liquidsonics.com/software_reverberate.htm

I'm not a fan of Altiverb - it sounds great but I find its ui dysfunctional.. so I use TLSpace mostly, but am very interested to experiment with Reverbate...

Traditional:
Valhalla Room
http://www.valhalladsp.com/valhallaroom

Weirder/non real:
Valhalla Shimmer
http://www.valhalladsp.com/valhallashimmer

d16 Toraverb
http://www.d16.pl/index.php?menu=228

2cAudio Aether
http://2caudio.com/products/aether

I love these last three...

What do you use most?

Comment: There's a new Valhalla verb on the block. I have yet to try it yet. http://www.valhalladsp.com/valhallavintageverb

Answer (score 3):

ValhallaRoom for warmth

Revibe/Reverb one for hifi/bright

LX480 for natural/transparent space - might replace with the newly cheap LXP bundle from Lexicon or Michael Carnes new Exponential Audio "Phoenix" depending who goes AAX first

DVerb for small room/ambience

TL space and Valhalla Shimmer for more out there stuff - not including delays like Echoboy or mod delay 3.

Comment: Forgot to give an honourable mention to Blackhole as well for out there stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

**ValhallaRoom** - for sweetening things up. It's light on resources and parameters can be automated without clicks.

[**ValhallaUberMod**](http://www.valhalladsp.com/valhallaubermod) - for nonlinear reverbs and sound design

**Reverberate** - mostly for sound design and experiments with my own IRs. I use the mod section a lot. Great plugin, very flexible.

**ZRev** - a "Schroeder” reverb from [U-HE Zebra](http://www.u-he.com/cms/zebra) pack. Good for ringing, resonating reverbs. It can turn almost any percussive sound into a hang drum beat :) Also good for sound design and creating metallic textures and ambiances.

Comment: I've never played around with ZRev. Thanks for reminding me about it!

Answer (score 0):

There's Reverb One and Revibe, although I don't own/use them yet, but I know that some mixers like them.  On a few occasions I've visited stages and heard both being used and they sound quite nice, lush, and transparent.

Right now based upon what tools I hve access to, I pretty much only TL Space for DX and FX (I lean toward the spring and plate IRs for FX), but I prefer RVerb for MX (score) - with Rverb I like using the studio space, 0.96 Size, 40-60ms Predelay, slightly rising high end on the EQ section, mix to taste against the dry.

Comment: Reverb One is fantastic. The algorithms are very superior, it's hard to find a setting that isn't at least *good*. I recently used it for live reverb in a theatrical installment (the FOH board was a Digidesign Venue) and it made for a stunning effect without much tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a thing for frozen reverb and delay. A great example is Ableton Live's Frozen Buildup preset, that can be tuned to great effect. But careful overdoing it, as it can quickly add so much mud to the mix.

Here's a question for you: do you ever use reverb without filtering the low end?

Answer (score 0):

The [TC Electronic VSS3 reverb](http://www.tcelectronic.com/vss3-tdm/) is great. It has numerous presets for post, and it's the same algorithm as found in the System 6000, so it's easy to match a reverb commonly found on dub stages. Great sounding early reflections and very useful for smaller stuff.

[Altiverb](http://www.audioease.com/Pages/Altiverb/index.php) is excellent for post, they've changed their UI in version 7 so you may find it easier to use now. They've also added an algorithmic reverb to the plugin which helps add brightness to darker IRs. Plus I dig supporting them because their customer service is so great, they're a small company, and they continue to supply awesome IRs to their customers (where else can you find IRs of the Great Pyramid of Giza or the Cistern in Fort Worden). It can be a DSP hog though, so I often find myself printing reverb returns with it before mixing.

[Echoboy](http://www.soundtoys.com/product/EchoBoy) by Soundtoys is great for weirder stuff. Plus, sometimes a little delay is all you need.

I haven't tried but I am interested in checking out:

IRCAM Verb, everything by Valhalla, Eventide 2016 Reverb and Blackhole, and the Lexicon PCM Bundle

Answer (score 0):

Ableton Reverb in Freeze Mode - If you like experimentation ( we all do:P ), espacially with                  bground sound, then this plugin can easily become a key ingredient.

Valhalla Room - don't need to describe, just a must have.

I'm gonna check 2CAudio stuff soon, their demos sounds fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

atm I'm using TrueVerb and IR-L from Waves.  Neither are all that fancy but they're relatively inexpensive, easy to use, and produce pretty decent results.
Favourite verbs would be Revibe, Reverb One, and Altiverb but those are all pretty much bank-breaking plugins.

Answer (score 0):

IRCAM Verb Session by Flux for natural verbs and distance.

TL Space for convolution (although I find it frustratingly "toiletty" at times).

I just bought Softube's TSAR-1R for more synthetic/retro but haven't really used it in anger yet.

Waves IR-L and Trueverb when working in Fairlight.

Answer (score 0):

nebula pro and divers reverb programs. Awesome...

Answer (score 0):

LEXICON PCM BUNdLE, for sure. 
I love the halls to create out of there effects.
In my try list is "valhalla room. 
After bougth the lexicons, I give up from altiveb, but I still like some of their impulses. 
TC VSS3 when available!